Create Bridge between Wifi and Ethernet on WiFi Linux development board
I have 2 Linux Wi-Fi development boards which includes Ethernet port as well and configured one board as AP and other board as STA. I would need to connect 2 laptops through Ethernet on both boards (one to AP and another one to STA) and send data between each other. so, the data flow would be like laptop1 will send data to STA board through Ethernet and STA board should send that data to the AP through wireless and AP should send it to the laptop2 through Ethernet. Both laptop should be in the same network 192.168.0.x. To do this, I have created bridge in AP and STA. (I'm sure whether bridge or NAT should be created in the STA.)
But, unable to communicate from laptop1 to laptops2. Laptop1 (192.168.1.99) which is connected to the STA board is able to send only till the STA board and whereas laptop2 (192.168.1.100) which is connected to the AP board is able to send to AP and STA board but, unable to reach to the laptop1.
STA board is able to communicate to both laptops but, AP board is unable to communicate to the Laptop1.
When I ping to laptop1 from AP or laptop2, the ARP Request broadcast message is being received at laptop1 and laptop1 is sending ARP reply as unicast to both AP and laptop2 but, somehow ARP Reply packet is failed to forward/reach to the laptop2 or AP.
As per my knowledge, NAT is not required since it is layer2 bridging, however it is not working with layer2 bridge. Is this expected behavior with bridge?
Please refer below network diagram.


Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

It is Ubuntu 22.04 and Linux Kernel is 5.10.120
